# Python program not working

Tags: python

i'm new to python so sorry if this insanely simple, but i'm kind of stuck and I've viewed the other questions regarding coin toss but this is even more simple than those:

put simply, why wont my prog work?

```
class Coin: 

    showing_heads=True
    value=1

    def show(self):
        if (self.showing_heads==True): 
            return "Heads" 
        else:              
            return "Tails" 

    def turn(self): 
        if (self.showing_heads==True): 
              self.showing_heads=False 
        else:                           
            self.showing_heads=True 

    def run_cointoss(2): 
          coin1=Coin() 
          coin2=Coin() 

          print "This is coin1" 
          print coin1.show() 
          print "This is coin2" 
          print coin2.show() 
          print "Turn them over" 
          coin1.turn() 
          coin2.turn() 
          print "This is coin1" 
          print coin1.show() 
          print "This is coin2" 
          print coin2.show()
```

Comment: It would really help if you told us what errors you're getting and what you expect your program to do.

Comment: It's not working because you are never calling the function `run_cointoss`

Comment: basically just to toss 2 different coins and show an answer, im getting a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" and i think its to do with the "  def run_cointoss(2): 
          coin1=Coin() 
          coin2=Coin() "

Comment: not a python user myself, but wouldn't `self.showing_heads = !self.showing_heads` be a nicer/more concise way of flipping between true/false?

Comment: What do you mean by "my prog don't work"?

Comment: Down-voted because of horrible title. Please change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is you're using 2 in function arguments. Function argument expect valid identifiers and `2` is not a valid identifier:

```
>>> def func(x):
    pass
... 
>>> def func(x = 2):
    pass
...
```

Your error:

```
>>> def func(2):
    pass
  File "<ipython-input-234-dc2d2489d3d8>", line 1
    def func(2):
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Secondly if your original code is indented as it is in question body, then you should move the definition of function `run_cointoss` outside of the class body.

Answer (score 1):

You should not create coins inside the `coin` class:

```
def run_cointoss(2): 
    coin1=Coin() 
    coin2=Coin()
```

Instead, create them after the class definition

```
class Coin:
    showing_heads=True
    value=1
    def show(self):
        if (self.showing_heads==True): 
            return "Heads" 
        else:              
            return "Tails" 

    def turn(self): 
        if (self.showing_heads==True): 
             self.showing_heads=False 
        else:                           
            self.showing_heads=True 
# Class definition is done

def run_cointoss(): 
      coin1=Coin() 
      coin2=Coin() 

      print "This is coin1" 
      print coin1.show() 
      print "This is coin2" 
      print coin2.show() 
      print "Turn them over" 
      coin1.turn() 
      coin2.turn() 
      print "This is coin1" 
      print coin1.show() 
      print "This is coin2" 
      print coin2.show() 

run_cointoss()
```